# Problems training Stanford Neural Network Parser

Tags: java, parsing, neural-network, stanford-nlp

I am currently trying to learn a "recursive neural network parser" following the steps shown in http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#rnn

Here are my settings:

- OS: Windows 7
- tool: custom Stanford parser full 2015-04-20
- data: Stanford University wikipedia page
- java: 1.8

Custom parser as I modified DVParserCostAndGradient.java, removing the usage of MulticoreWrapper at line 273 (because it holds up at this point):

```
MulticoreWrapper<Tree, Pair<DeepTree, DeepTree>> wrapper = new MulticoreWrapper<Tree, Pair<DeepTree, DeepTree>>(op.trainOptions.trainingThreads, new ScoringProcessor());
for (Tree tree : trainingBatch) {
    wrapper.put(tree);
}
wrapper.join();
scoreTiming.done();
while (wrapper.peek()) {
    Pair<DeepTree, DeepTree> result = wrapper.poll();
    [...]
```

which gives the following piece of code:

```
ScoringProcessor scorer = new ScoringProcessor();
for (Tree tree : trainingBatch) {
    Pair<DeepTree, DeepTree> result = scorer.process(tree);
    [...]
```

I launched the following commands:

/1/

```
java -mx2g -cp "ejml-0.23.jar;stanford-parser-custom.jar" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser .\models\englishPCFG.ser.gz .\plain\1.txt > .\treebank\1.txt
```

/2/

```
java -mx2g -cp "stanford-parser-custom.jar;stanford-parser-3.5.2-models.jar" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.dvparser.CacheParseHypotheses -model models/englishPCFG.ser.gz -treebank treebank 1 -output cached.wsj.ser.gz -numThreads 2 2> log.txt
```

/3/

```
java -mx2g -cp "ejml-0.23.jar;stanford-parser-custom.jar" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.dvparser.DVParser -cachedTrees cached.wsj.ser.gz -train -testTreebank treebank 1 -debugOutputFrequency 500 -trainingThreads 1 -parser models/englishPCFG.ser.gz -dvIterations 40 -dvBatchSize 25 -wordVectorFile t2.txt -model models/RNNtry.ser.gz -unkword "-UNKNOWN-"
```

Where t2.txt is the embedding found in "stanford-parser-3.5.2-models.jar\edu\stanford\nlp\models\parser\nndep\wsj_SD.gz"

The first problem I have is executing /2/, in log.txt, I can read for every sentence:

```
WARNING: filtered all trees for
```

Followed by some parse tree I believe.

When launching /3/, I have:

```
Iteration 0 batch 0
Converting trees ... done [0,1 sec].
Scoring trees ... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Failed to get any hypothesis trees for
```

Followed by most likely the same thing as in /2/.

And after that, the process seems to hang up. The error in /3/ is most certainly a consequence of the one in /2/. Has anyone got an idea of why every tree is filtered in step /2/ ?

Thanks in advance,

EDIT:

The text given to the LexicalizedParser module is the unsegmented text from the page stripped from all HTML code:

```
Origins and early years (1885–1906)
The university officially opened on October 1, 1891 to 555 students. On the university's opening day, Founding President David Starr Jordan (1851–1931) said to Stanford's Pioneer Class: " is hallowed by no traditions; it is hampered by none. Its finger posts all point forward." However, much preceded the opening and continued for several years until the death of the last Founder, Jane Stanford, in 1905 and the destruction of the 1906 earthquake.
```

For which LexicalizedParser outputs:

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP
      (NP
        (NP (NNS Origins))
        (CC and)
        (NP (JJ early) (NNS years)))
      (PRN (-LRB- -LRB-)
        (NP
          (NP (NNP 1885))
          (: --)
          (NP (CD 1906)))
        (-RRB- -RRB-)))
    (ADVP
      (NP (DT The) (NN university))
      (RB officially))
    (VP (VBD opened)
      (PP (IN on)
        (NP (NNP October) (CD 1) (, ,) (CD 1891)))
      (PP (TO to)
        (NP (CD 555) (NNS students))))
    (. .)))

[...]
```

I may add that trees in the stacktrace seem fully annotated, here is the warning given in step /2/ for the sentence:

```
WARNING: filtered all trees for (ROOT (S^ROOT-v (@S^ROOT-v| VP^S-VBF-v_ ... ADVP^S< NP^S[ (NP^S (@NP^S| NP^NP-R_ PRN^N
P] (@NP^S| NP^NP-R_ (NP^NP-R (@NP^NP-R| NP^NP-B_ CC^NP-C> NP^NP-B] (@NP^NP-R| NP^NP-B_ CC^NP-C> (@NP^NP-R| NP^NP-B_ (NP
^NP-B (NNS^NP Origins))) (CC^NP-C and)) (NP^NP-B (@NP^NP-B| NNS^NP_ JJ^NP[ (JJ^NP early) (@NP^NP-B| NNS^NP_ (NNS^NP yea
rs))))))) (PRN^NP (@PRN^NP| NP^PRN-R_ -RRB-^PRN> -LRB-^PRN[ (-LRB-^PRN -LRB-) (@PRN^NP| NP^PRN-R_ -RRB-^PRN> (@PRN^NP| 
NP^PRN-R_ (NP^PRN-R (@NP^PRN-R| NP^NP-B_ :^NP> NP^NP-B] (@NP^PRN-R| NP^NP-B_ :^NP> (@NP^PRN-R| NP^NP-B_ (NP^NP-B (NNP^N
P 1885))) (:^NP --)) (NP^NP-B (CD^NP 1906))))) (-RRB-^PRN -RRB-)))))) (@S^ROOT-v| VP^S-VBF-v_ .^S> ADVP^S< (ADVP^S (@AD
VP^S| RB^ADVP_ NP^ADVP-B[ (NP^ADVP-B (@NP^ADVP-B| NN^NP_ DT^NP[ (DT^NP The) (@NP^ADVP-B| NN^NP_ (NN^NP university)))) (
@ADVP^S| RB^ADVP_ (RB^ADVP officially)))) (@S^ROOT-v| VP^S-VBF-v_ .^S> (@S^ROOT-v| VP^S-VBF-v_ (VP^S-VBF-v (@VP^S-VBF-v
| VBD^VP_ PP^VP> PP^VP] (@VP^S-VBF-v| VBD^VP_ PP^VP> (@VP^S-VBF-v| VBD^VP_ (VBD^VP opened)) (PP^VP (@PP^VP| IN^PP_ NP^P
P-B] (@PP^VP| IN^PP_ (IN^PP on)) (NP^PP-B (@NP^PP-B| NNP^NP_ ... ,^NP> CD^NP] (@NP^PP-B| NNP^NP_ CD^NP> ,^NP> (@NP^PP-B
| NNP^NP_ CD^NP> (@NP^PP-B| NNP^NP_ (NNP^NP October)) (CD^NP 1)) (,^NP ,)) (CD^NP 1891)))))) (PP^VP (@PP^VP| TO^PP_ NP^
PP-B] (@PP^VP| TO^PP_ (TO^PP to)) (NP^PP-B (@NP^PP-B| NNS^NP_ CD^NP[ (CD^NP 555) (@NP^PP-B| NNS^NP_ (NNS^NP students)))
)))))) (.^S .))))) (.$$. .$.))
```

Comment: In what form is the text in the files you feed to the parser?

Comment: @pnadczuk : I edited the OP giving you this information (and others things that may be relevant to the subject).

Comment: @G_Zeus Have you solved the problem? I'm facing similar problem. Mine stops at "Scoring trees ... "

Comment: @G_Zeus I looked at your wsj_SD.gz file. It might be a formatting problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111411/neural-network-stanford-parser-word2vector-format-error-during-training