# Neural Network Stanford parser word2vector format error during training

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to train a model with Stanford neural network dependency parser for English. It does not accept a standard word2vector file with 100 dimensions. It generates an error message.
I am using the embedded words as defined in this Web page: 
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8nESzOdPhLsdWF2S1Ayb1RkTXc/view?usp=sharing][1]
I have dowloaded the data as a text file in myPC. I am using the parameter -embeddingSize 100
but the parser generates an error message:
Embedding File /../.../sskip.100.vectors: #Words=243004, dim=1
The dimension of embedding file does not match config.embeddingSize

I can see that each Word is defined by 100 values. Any suggestion about problems with this word embedding format for the Stanford Parser?

Here are the first words and the initial line:

```
243003 100
</s> 0.004003 0.004419 -0.003830 -0.003278 0.001367 0.003021 0.000941 0.000211 -0.003604 0.002218 -0.004356 0.001250 -0.000751 -0.000957 -0.003316 -0.001882 0.002579 0.003025 0.002969 0.001597 0.001545 -0.003803 -0.004096 0.004970 0.003801 0.003090 -0.000604 0.004016 -0.000495 0.000735 -0.000149 -0.002983 0.001312 -0.001337 -0.003825 0.004754 0.004379 -0.001095 -0.000226 0.000509 -0.003638 -0.004007 0.004555 0.000063 -0.002582 -0.003042 -0.003076 0.001697 0.000201 0.001331 -0.004214 -0.003808 -0.000130 0.001144 0.002550 -0.003170 0.004080 0.000927 0.001120 -0.000608 0.002986 -0.002288 -0.002097 0.002158 -0.000753 0.001031 0.001805 -0.004089 -0.001983 0.002914 0.004232 0.003932 -0.003047 -0.002108 -0.000909 0.002001 -0.003788 0.002998 0.002788 -0.001599 -0.001552 -0.002238 0.004229 0.003912 -0.001180 0.004215 0.004820 0.001815 0.004983 -0.003111 -0.001532 -0.002107 -0.002907 0.002815 0.001579 0.000425 -0.002194 0.001524 0.003059 0.000194 
the 0.314845 -0.594966 0.364453 -0.303990 -0.163298 -0.208138 -0.063397 -0.274273 0.008039 0.313427 0.077980 0.230821 -0.303666 0.069646 0.034396 0.713454 0.144248 -0.182218 0.363876 0.619664 -0.351316 0.002414 0.434149 -0.429740 0.368150 -0.709280 -0.076584 0.168682 -0.111134 0.291124 0.056759 0.236357 -0.216234 -0.151878 -0.429654 0.020701 0.152160 -0.012689 -0.365258 -0.284180 -0.031743 0.322464 -0.294811 0.017445 -0.004059 0.215779 -0.119879 -0.232236 -0.321151 0.301774 -0.126148 -0.517174 0.345968 0.640385 -0.217424 0.308738 0.219053 -0.115701 -0.205319 -0.211564 0.195052 -0.465845 0.079989 -0.314120 -0.489292 0.393189 0.506710 0.444550 0.090913 -0.041937 0.019073 -0.211669 -0.068794 -0.324646 0.286798 -0.096603 -0.458527 -0.017360 -0.027033 0.193178 0.239730 0.050892 0.067579 -0.175215 0.044952 0.132419 -0.129821 0.273940 0.560339 0.021715 0.215951 0.731709 0.132121 0.113550 0.430923 0.344183 -0.263545 0.435532 -0.201218 -0.027319 
, 0.061619 -0.565545 0.125936 -0.284422 -0.169127 0.460509 0.006625 -0.329331 0.336665 0.193879 -0.132434 0.249105 -0.175773 -0.082793 -0.508019 0.721060 0.760420 0.176019 0.246262 0.204314 -0.036362 0.074625 0.350433 -0.545271 0.286622 0.015969 0.181921 0.125430 0.076984 0.101759 -0.054494 -0.030594 -0.198813 0.228708 -0.216355 0.340003 0.244340 -0.195765 -0.119334 -0.120226 -0.318529 0.204634 0.185596 0.069793 0.452572 -0.086685 0.141807 -0.011995 -0.132059 -0.212667 -0.142585 -0.398395 -0.025111 0.381179 -0.108959 0.118045 0.097696 0.146426 -0.037016 -0.224785 -0.025545 -0.028420 0.267363 -0.368773 0.066806 0.377338 -0.069999 0.191271 0.208339 0.765346 -0.036333 0.458936 -0.107518 -0.250389 -0.237289 0.171875 0.037814 0.242127 0.013300 -0.237103 0.670932 0.376154 -0.036636 -0.018235 0.258066 -0.027170 -0.148790 0.426763 0.525802 0.158871 -0.257020 0.297436 0.124205 0.011005 0.495096 -0.158856 0.035228 0.189957 -0.267969 0.279380 
. -0.116517 -0.631137 0.172816 -0.262048 -0.040504 0.169117 -0.205499 -0.148350 0.189173 -0.031506 -0.269349 0.609523 0.305698 0.023472 -0.190445 0.771157 0.612304 -0.063000 0.169066 0.124187 -0.252965 0.417390 0.571047 -0.499795 0.302955 -0.171781 -0.112887 -0.118344 -0.068801 0.051599 0.114658 0.144728 -0.341774 0.481746 -0.240515 0.133912 0.308567 -0.004850 0.110450 -0.254397 -0.202240 0.070778 0.094780 -0.098785 0.370708 0.007306 -0.049338 0.102309 0.098400 -0.195322 0.121543 -0.620514 -0.073040 0.195811 -0.309233 -0.020104 0.643815 0.071323 -0.093095 -0.374297 0.072836 -0.204757 0.191280 -0.432853 0.101545 0.427208 0.164303 0.246313 0.311429 0.849791 0.004568 0.328126 -0.185645 -0.371651 -0.270725 -0.013400 0.010909 0.024112 -0.176938 -0.180654 0.428156 0.150460 -0.219369 -0.015102 0.349785 0.259967 -0.081237 0.262176 0.586780 0.224804 -0.204084 0.548801 0.081115 0.046538 0.352024 0.230098 -0.050318 0.615924 -0.423620 0.186570
```

Comment: Can you post a brief excerpt of the `sskip.100.vectors` file? I can't download 200+ MB to check the format.

Comment: It is likely that this file is not formatted how the parser expects it to be.

Comment: I want to reformat this, but I don't even know how to begin...

Comment: You shouldn't have that "243003 100" line.  It thinks you have "243003" as a word with "100" as the vector (hence the dimension=1 error).  Just delete that first line.

Comment: You should have a "\t" separate the word and the vector.  The values of the vector are separated by a space as you have it.

Comment: Thanks!, Both suggestions solved the problem